# adding a source to bytefield

Tags: tables, citing, bytefield

below you see my minimum example. Take a look at the second figure with the \includegraphics. I could add a field for citations as shown below with a tabular inside the figure. This works pretty well. What I want to do now is to add the same field for citations to the bytefield, but it doesn't work. I also tried it with a \makebox, but this also lead to no sulition. Has someone an idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\bytefieldbox}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1em]{32}
        \bitheader{0-31} \\
        \bitbox{4}{Version} & \bitbox{4}{IHL} & \bitbox{8}{Type of Service} & \bitbox{16}{Total Length} \\
        \bitbox{16}{Identification} & \bitbox{3}{Flags} & \bitbox{13}{Fragment Offset} \\
        \bitbox{8}{\emph{Time to Live}} & \bitbox{8}{Protocol} & \bitbox{16}{Header Checksum} \\
        \bitbox{32}{\emph{Source Address}} \\
        \bitbox{32}{\emph{Destination Address}}\\
        \bitbox{24}{Options} & \bitbox{8}{Padding (if any)} \\
    \end{bytefield}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}   

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\\

{\footnotesize Source: based on ...}
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `bytefield` doesn't like to be in `tabular` or in `\sbox`. I suggest a low level trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\bytefieldbox}
\newenvironment{sourcedbytefield}[3][]
 {\def\source{#3}\setbox\bytefieldbox=\hbox\bgroup\begin{bytefield}[#1]{#2}}
 {\end{bytefield}\egroup
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
  \usebox{\bytefieldbox}\\
  \footnotesize\source
  \end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\sourcedincludegraphics}[3][]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\\
  \footnotesize#3
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{sourcedbytefield}[bitwidth=1em]{32}{Source: based on ...}
  \bitheader{0-31} \\
  \bitbox{4}{Version} & \bitbox{4}{IHL} & \bitbox{8}{Type of Service} & \bitbox{16}{Total Length} \\
  \bitbox{16}{Identification} & \bitbox{3}{Flags} & \bitbox{13}{Fragment Offset} \\
  \bitbox{8}{\emph{Time to Live}} & \bitbox{8}{Protocol} & \bitbox{16}{Header Checksum} \\
  \bitbox{32}{\emph{Source Address}} \\
  \bitbox{32}{\emph{Destination Address}}\\
  \bitbox{24}{Options} & \bitbox{8}{Padding (if any)}
\end{sourcedbytefield}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}   

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\sourcedincludegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}{Source: based on ...}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that there shouldn't be a trailing `\\` in the `bytefield` environment (remove `\\` from the last line).

[image]

Comment: this is great, thank you! what I like to have now is to move the "source: based on ..." a little more to the left. I tried it with \hspace, but this didn't work.

Comment: @Robert Add something like `\hspace*{1em}` before the closing brace in the definition.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. `\hspace*{1em}` works fine. I tried it before without the asterisk and it didn't work. Could you please explain why you need an asterisk in this case?

Comment: @Robert In `tabular` trailing spaces in a cell are removed (usually it is just a space token, but this removal can also affect other spaces). With `\hspace*` you ensure the space is never removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap your `bytefield` in a group `{...}`, it works fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\bytefieldbox}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
{\lineskip=1pt
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1em]{32}
        \bitheader{0-31} \\
        \bitbox{4}{Version} & \bitbox{4}{IHL} & \bitbox{8}{Type of Service} & \bitbox{16}{Total Length} \\
        \bitbox{16}{Identification} & \bitbox{3}{Flags} & \bitbox{13}{Fragment Offset} \\
        \bitbox{8}{\emph{Time to Live}} & \bitbox{8}{Protocol} & \bitbox{16}{Header Checksum} \\
        \bitbox{32}{\emph{Source Address}} \\
        \bitbox{32}{\emph{Destination Address}}\\
        \bitbox{24}{Options} & \bitbox{8}{Padding (if any)} 
    \end{bytefield}
   }\\
    {\footnotesize Source: based on ...}
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}   

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\\

{\footnotesize Source: based on ...}
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, the lines are doubled.

Comment: @egreg Indeed. It seems to be possible to get the correct spacing by removing the `\\ `  before `\end{bytefield}`

Comment: I was mentioning the rules in the body of `bytefield`. You can cure them by adding `\lineskip=1pt` after the initial brace that starts the group where `bytefield` is in.

Comment: @egreg My bad, I did not notice it, its is due to the combination with the `tabular`

Comment: @BambOo This looks like I had it once before, but I wasn't able to get to this result once again. What i don't like in this case is, that the distande of the source is really far away from the bytefield.

Comment: @Robert this is related to previous comments, the code has been corrected